# Safe a sorted list in shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to use the shared preferences to save a list of integers. it's simple by using the putStringSet() methode.

```
final Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();

for (final Station station : stations) {
    set.add(String.valueOf(station.getId()));
}
editor.putStringSet(USER_STATIONS, set);
```

but there's a big problem. the list isn't sorted anymore after loading the prefereneces with getStringSet()

Is there an other/better way than save the list as json or as a string with comma seperated values?

Comment: I like the idea of a comma separated string if it's just integers. You could also fake an array by doing something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050845/752320).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to save sorting with preferences (at least SharedPreferences reference is clear about that) , instead you can do it with LiteSQL or by creating a custom file: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal .